# Is it faster to save data in a std::vector or a .txt file?

Tags: c++, performance, file, data-structures

I want to save a large amount of data of type `float` somewhere. Performance is a top priority. Is it faster to save the data in a `std::vector` or in a .txt file?

Comment: memory is faster than disk, binary is typically faster than text

Comment: memory is fast. but how big your data?

Comment: i want to save the coordinates of 500 or 1000 balls every moment. the balls fall free in a room and collide with each other.
this means the .txt file could be about 5MB or bigger

Comment: It doesn't matter how much data you have, unless you plan to exceed the total available physical RAM.  Even then, vector probably comes out on top.  Disk is very slow.  Even solid-state disk is slow.  Not to mention that if you stored the data as actual text (instead of raw binary), the conversion is also slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing in hard disk is slower than accessing th memory. The only thing is you need to think of a way not to run out of memory